# Cambiar color de TextField al escribir

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy en una tarea para la universidad y me piden **cambiar el color del background** de un textfield **al momento en que el usuario ingresa un carácter**, sé que para cambiar el fondo se ocupa el .SetBackgroud(color red), pero solo lo he podido configurar de esa forma apretando un botón para que este cambie el color del fondo. Alguien sabe como hacerlo para que al ingresar un carácter el fondo cambie? gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal ahí te paso una forma de hacerlo muy similar a la que te pasó el anterior usuario, fijate de posicionarte sobre ésa clase, **botón derecho y luego "Run" -> "Ass Java Application"**, una vez que se te abre la ventana swing, ingresá algun caractér en el JTextField.

**Forma número 1:**

Directamente del JTextField llamamos a un KeyListener, nos evita tener que declarar el text.addKeyListener(this); así como también zafamos de implementar la interface en la clase y la implementación del resto de sus métodos, porque directamente la estamos llamando desde el botón.

**El resultado es que en forma muy simple, tocando cualquier tecla cambiamos su fondo.**

Lo ideal en un caso como éste sería aplicar Lambda, **pero no podemos**, ya que **la interfaz declara más de un método** dentro de su interface.

```
package com.soa.frames;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Panel {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField text;

    public Panel() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        text = new JTextField(10);

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        frame.setTitle("Change JTextField Color");
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(text, borderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        /* Metemos la interfaz directamente dentro del boton, sin implementar nada */
        text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                text.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();

    }

}
```

**Forma número 2:**

En la siguiente no es más que un condicional, donde sí implementamos la interfaz y nos obliga a declarar todos los métodos dentro de la misma. Si queremos que el fondo del JTextField cambie dependiendo del Codigo de la letra que ingresemos entonces este código va bien, no sé los códigos de las letras pero se averiguan simplemente.

```
package com.soa.frames;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Panel implements KeyListener {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextField text;

    public Panel() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel =new JPanel();
        text = new JTextField(10);

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        frame.setTitle("Change JTextField Color");
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(text, borderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        text.addKeyListener( this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();

    }

    /* Al ser una interface te obliga a definir todos los métodos, sin embargo sólo usamos uno */
    /* Mandé cualquier código de tecla, total ni sé cual es el 65 */
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(KeyEvent.getKeyText(0))) {
            text.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else {
            text.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        }

    }

    /* Estos métodos estamos obligados a llamarlos por ser una interface pero no los vamos a definir, sólo declarar */
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: @bastian Te hice dos ejemplos íntegros, espero que te sirvan los dos, abrazos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    ((JTextField) e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.red);
   }
  });
```

Comment: Aunque este código puede solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, sería ideal que explicaras cómo funciona. Las respuestas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Te recomiendo que leas [answer], donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus respuestas, y que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y así ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué "probar eso" crees que solucionaría el problema.